Functoriality of Thom Space as Mapping Cone
One of the most general definitions of the Thom space associated to a real vector bundle $\xi\colon V \to X$ is as $\newcommand{\Th}{\operatorname{Th}} \Th(\xi) := C(V \setminus X \hookrightarrow V)$, the mapping cone of the inclusion of the complement of the zero-section into the total space. It is then said that $\Th$ assembles into a functor¹
$$\newcommand{\VectBunR}{\mathrm{VectBun}_{\mathbb{R}}}\newcommand{\Top}{\mathrm{Top}}
    \Th\colon \VectBunR \to \Top_*
$$
from the category of real vector bundles over topological spaces into the category of pointed spaces (where we take the cone point as basepoint).
I have a hard time figuring out how to actually define the action of $\Th$ on morphisms. Perhaps naively one would expect the functoriality just to come from functoriality of the mapping cone, but given two vector bundles $V \to X$ and $W \to Y$ and a map $f\colon X \to Y$ as well as a bundle map $\tilde{f}\colon V \to W$ covering $f$, it is unclear to me how to obtain a map $V \setminus X \to W \setminus Y$, seeing as $\tilde{f}$ does not need to carry non-zero vector to non-zero vectors.
The only other approach that comes to mind is to compare this definition of $\Th$ with another one given on a more restrictive domain and see whether one can "transfer" functoriality of that construction over and extend it to all vector bundles, but this also hasn't been of great use: The perhaps obvious candidate for this is $D(V) / S(E)$, the quotient of the disk bundle of $\xi$ by its sphere bundle, defined for bundles with euclidean metric; its functoriality is obtained by turning a bundle map $\tilde{f}\colon V \to W$ into a map $\operatorname{int} D(V) \to \operatorname{int} D(W)$ by composing with homeomorphisms $\operatorname{int} D(V) \overset{\cong}{\to} V$ and $W \overset{\cong}{\to} \operatorname{int} D(W)$ obtained from the metric and then extending this to a map of Thom spaces by sending $[S(V)]$ to $[S(W)]$, as I discussed in this answer.
The (homotopy) equivalence of this construction to the general one follows from the commutativity of the diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
S(V) @>>> D(V) \\
@VVV @VVV \\
{V \setminus X} @>>> V
\end{CD}
and the fact that the vertical arrows are homotopy equivalences. Unfortunately, it does not seem to me like the functoriality obtainable from this transfers easily to the non-metrizable case: Here, the homotopies obtained from the metric seem to be indispensable.
To make a long story short, my question is: What's the action on morphisms that makes $\Th\colon \VectBunR \to \Top_*$ into a functor?

¹Here and throughout I'd hope for strict functoriality, given a suitable choice of model for the cone, but I'm also happy with pseudo-functoriality.

N.b. All sources I've looked at either take this functoriality for granted outright or state that it is easy, which is quite strange to me. Perhaps I am really missing something obvious?

This is an easy mistake to make (I made it when first looking at this question), but the Thom space construction is not functorial. Let us consider the case that the base space $X$ is compact Hausdorff. Then, the Thom space of $V\rightarrow X$ should unanimously be the Alexandroff compactification $V^+$. However, not every bundle map $\overline{f}\colon V\rightarrow W$ extends to a map $V^+\rightarrow W^+$ via $\infty_V\mapsto\infty_W$. This would be equivalent to properness of $\overline{f}$, however if $\overline{f}_x\colon V_x\rightarrow W_{f(x)}$ is not injective for some $x\in X$, then $\overline{f}^{-1}(0_{f(x)})$ contains a non-trivial subspace of $V_x$ and is thus non-compact. It follows that it is a necessary (in fact, also sufficient) condition that $\overline{f}$ be fiberwise injective for this extension to exist.
In conclusion, we see that the natural collection of maps w.r.t. which the Thom space construction is functorial are the fiberwise injective bundle maps rather than all bundle maps (and I would assume the references you consulted were implicitly only considering fiberwise isomorphisms). It is obvious that your mapping cone construction is functorial w.r.t. fiberwise injective bundle maps.
Let me also point out that another possible construction of the Thom space is to take the fiber-wise compactification to obtain an $(\mathbb{R}^n\cup\{\infty\})$-bundle with a distinguished section at infinity and then collapse that section. This can also be seen to be functorial w.rt. fiberwise injective bundle maps by first fiberwise extending to the Alexandroff compactification and then passing to the quotient. There are minor technical difficulties (extending maps to the Alexandroff compactification is continuous w.r.t. compact-open topologies under appropriate conditions), but the upshot is that this also defines Thom spaces for other types of bundles like $\mathrm{Top}(n)$-bundles.

...of course, and it's so obvious, too. Thank you for pointing this out. In my defense, the paper I'm reading that motivated the question then contains a mistake :)
